# LINQ Query condition based on a condition

Tags: linq, conditional-statements

I have a LINQ query as follows:

```
   var query = from r in Context.Role()
        join rg in Context.RoleGroup() on r.RoleId equals rg.FkRoleId
        where r.RoleName != "guests" && r.RoleName != "SystemAdmin"
    select rg;
```

However, I need an additional condition to include, that SystemAdmin should not be excluded based on external condition (say, the logged in user is superuser).

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347498/how-to-add-conditional-condition-to-linq-query-based-on-a-previously-returned-va), I modified the query like below:

```
       var query = from r in Context.Role()
        join rg in Context.RoleGroup() on r.RoleId equals rg.FkRoleId
        where r.RoleName != "guests" && (userId == 1 || r.RoleName != "SystemAdmin")
    select rg;
```

But I still can see SystemAdmin role in the output even if the userId is not 1. How can I get the desired output?

Comment: If use Id is not 1 then you have `r.RoleName != "guests" && (false || r.RoleName != "SystemAdmin")` which is same as your first condition. That means user Id is equal to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query goes as follows:

```
var query = from r in Context.Role()
    join rg in Context.RoleGroup() on r.RoleId equals rg.FkRoleId
    where r.RoleName != "guests" && (userId == 1 || (userId> 1 && r.RoleName != "SystemAdmin"))
select rg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for dynamic where condition:

```
           if (printType == "BatchWise")
            {
                whereCondition = "BatchNo.Equals(@" + 0 + ")";
                array[0] = Convert.ToString(printNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                whereCondition = "TagNo.Equals(@" + 0 + ")";
                array[0] = Convert.ToString(printNumber);
            }

            using (var inventoryDb = new InventoryDb())
            {
                var pricingInfo = (from price in invDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
                                   where tagDtl.AvailableQuantity > 0
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       PricingNo = price.PricingNo,
                                       ............
                                   }).Where(whereCondition, array).ToList();
            }
```